# I am getting Error " Variable does not exist: queryResult"

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, dynamic-soql

Please Find the code

```
 <apex:page controller="SOQLController" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputText value="Enter Name" />
        <apex:inputText value="{!name}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Query" action="{!query}“ />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>

public class SOQLController {
    public String name {
        get { return name;}
        set { name = value;}
    } 
    public PageReference query() {
        String qryString = 'SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE ' +
            '(IsDeleted = false and Name like \'%' + name + '%\')';
        queryResult = Database.query(qryString);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that all your controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the query method, you are using the queryResult variable without defining / declaring it.

```
List<Contact> queryResult = Database.query(qryString);
```

this should resolve the error.

check [this reference](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) for more details on Dynamic SOQL

just curious to understand your complete requirement ? the query action method associated with the button is running a query and capturing the results.. but you seem to not using the results anywhere.

Comment: As the result will be a list of Contact object surely `Contact[] queryResult = Database.query(qryString);` or better `for (Contact c : Database.query(qryString)) { ... }`.

Comment: thx @KeithC , I hv updated my answer.